# HttpClient.GetAsync() selectively ignoring query parameter

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, visual-studio-2022

I have a very simple method for querying a webpage and parsing the results. The body of the response isn't the problem, the problem is that the request generated by the `GetAsync(string)` or `GetAsync(Uri)` methods seem to selectively ignore a certain query parameter. I say it is *selectively* ignoring it, because it is ignoring the same parameter **regardless of the order in which they appear.**

When I check the `RequestMessage` property of the returned `HttpResponseMessage`, the `RequestUri` shows the complete uri correctly, except that it's missing the very specific "o=data" parameter, and the response body confirms that the parameter wasn't present in the request because the content should be sorted by date if it was present (but it isn't).

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new() { BaseAddress = new("https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/busca") };

public static async Task<ResultDocument[]> GetResults(string name)
        {
            var query = new Uri($"https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/busca?q={Uri.EscapeDataString(name)}&o=data");
            //var query = "?q={name}&o=data" the exact same problem happens whether I use BaseAddress or not.
            var resp = await client.GetAsync(query);
            // Rest of the function parsing the result's body.
        }
```

[image: Specifically the "o" query parameter disappears from the request.]

***UPDATE:***
I've tried to rename the parameter. <strike>It works if the parameter is named "w", and it works if the parameter is named "or". It **ONLY disappears if it has the name "o" (which is the one I need).**</strike>
Doesn't work. Any other parameter disappears if `name` has a space character.

***UPDATE:***
Turns out the problem only happens when `name` has a space character. Even if it escaped. Code updated.

No space:
[image: No space]

With space:
[image: With space]

Showing `name.ToCharArray()` when "o" disappears. (The method here is being called directly from Program.cs):
[image]

***UPDATE:***
It seems the problem might be with the default `HttpMessageHandler`.
When I implement a custom handler just to see *how* `HttpClient` is generating the `HttpRequestMessage`, the `RequestUri` is correct in the request. And also notice that here the space character shows escaped as `"%20"` and not as `'+'`, which is how it should be, since `Uri.EscapeDataString(string)` escapes it with `"%20"` and not `'+'`.
[image]

Comment: Why are you repeating the base-URI in `BaseAddress` and in the `Uri` constructor?

Comment: @Dai I'm not. I just repeated in this example because I was trying to pass an ```Uri``` object rather than a string, but if I use the line commented out in the code it yields the same result.

Comment: BTW, you're building that URI incorrectly: you do need to encode querystring values using `Uri.EscapeDataString` - otherwise if your `name` string contains non-URI-safe characters (like a space `' '`, ampersand `'&'`or even an apostrophe can break things easily. i.e. do `new Uri($"https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/busca?q={Uri.EscapeDataString(name)}&o=data")`

Comment: @Dai Thank you, I did that. It turns out the problem didn't solve itself. It only happens when ```name``` doesn't contain spaces. If it does, the other parameter disappears (even if I escape the ```name``` parameter with Uri.EscapeDataString(string)). Any thoughts?

Comment: Please show us all of the **full and exact** input string values involved, and then the output value of `Uri.ToString()` and `Uri.OriginalString` (it's common for them to be different) - both when `name` has spaces and when it doesn't.

Comment: @Dai I added those prints before reading your comment. I'll update them. Please hold on.

Comment: This is _weird_ - the only explanation I can think of is if  `name` contains any zero-valued characters, e.g. `\0` (aka ASCII `NUL`), which _might_ cause the querystring to be terminated at that point. Please try to reproduce the issue in a single **short** `Program.cs` file. Also, please show us the contents of `name.ToCharArray()` when the `&o` param goes missing.

Comment: The ```name``` parameter in this case comes from a TextBox.Text property, I don't think it returns ```'\0'```, does it? Besides, ```'\0'``` usually show up (if any) in these little watcher things when debugging.

Comment: @Dai The same thing happens when the method is called from Program.cs with parameters "test" and "test name". The "o" parameter disappears only when using "test name".

Comment: @Dai Updated with print showinf contents of ```name.ToCharArray()``` when it contains a space (and o disappears).

Comment: I tried your code at my end in Linqpad and I can't reproduce the issue: the URI is always correctly-formed - but I always get a HTTP 403 Forbidden response - so I wonder if another possibility is that your request was sent-out correctly but received a redirection response which mangled the URI, and that redirection would appear in `HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage`. What appears in Fiddler Classic? (Fiddler Classic can decrypt HTTPS traffic: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler )

Comment: You got a 403 because it requires the Host, User-Agent and Accept headers (maybe not all three of them, but by adding these three solves it). Here I get a HTTP 200 as it should be, the only problem is that the contents of the body isn't sorted as it should, and I can't sort it myself. Since the result is paginated, if it isn't sorted, I can't tell whether the most recent entry is actually in the page. and I only need the most recent entries.

Comment: @Dai You are right. If you escape the space character with %20 there is a redirect, and the redirect ignores the other parameters. The name has to escape space characters with + from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of help from @Dai, we finally figured out the problem.
The server responded with a redirect if the space character in the `name` was escaped with `%20`, and the redirection destination ignored the other parameters. **It turns out the problem was with the server, and not the code.**

To fix this I simply changed the line:

```
var query = new Uri($"https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/busca?q={Uri.EscapeDataString(name)}&o=data");
```

To:

```
var query = new Uri($"https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/diarios/busca?q={Uri.EscapeDataString(name).Replace("%20", "+")}&o=data");
```

I left the `Uri.EscapeDataString(string)` and only replaced `%20` because other characters escaped with `%xx` (such as double quote `%22`) still works fine and causes no faulty redirection.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. Note that `+` can only be used instead of `%20` in querystring values: you can't use `+` for spaces in the path portion of a URI, for example.